# How to read semantic graph in NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

I am new with NetworkX. I would like to know, is it possible to read a semantic graph (triples) in networkX?

```
graph_example.csv
"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"
...........
```

In the above example "a", "c", "d", "f" are distinct node labels and "b" and "e" are distinct edge labels (the example presents a directed graph).

I have tried the following.

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('graph_example.csv',create_using=nx.DiGraph(),delimiter=',', nodetype=str, encoding="utf-8")
```

However, it is giving me following error.

```
TypeError: Failed to convert edge data ([.....]) to dictionary.
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html?highlight=read_edgelist#networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist). In your example, the node labels would actually be `a, b, d` and `e`. The last token(s) on the line (`c` and `f` in your case) would be the edge attribute(s). In order to parse the edge attributes, you need to provide a list of tuples with attribute names and types:

```
read_edgelist(..., data=(('my_edge_label', str),))
```

Not sure you need the quotes in csv.

Hope this helps.